# animation on every mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover, css-animations

I have created a bounce animation. This bounce animation is to an image and is triggered on mouseover. Currently,the animation occurs only once,What I want is that it should bounce on every mouseover.

HTML code:

```
<div class="hair">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair1" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);" >
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair2" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair3" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair4" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair5" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair6" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair7" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair8" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
    <img src="images/single.png" id="hair9" class="hair_animate"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function bounce(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).className = "animated bounce_css";
}
```

CSS:

```
.hair{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}

.animated {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
    /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    /*-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -o-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -o-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        -o-transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-35px);
    }
}
.bounce_css {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
    -o-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
}
```

Comment: You posted the exact same question yesterday, Am I right?

Comment: no..that was regarding some other issue,this time around ,the animation is done,but its happening only the first time when I mouseover.I have tried some other things like linear,infinite in css ,but that does not matches what i want,i.e bounce should occur on every mouseover,currently its happennig only once??

Comment: you can go and have a look at my activity log

Comment: I saw some tutorials on the internet and all of them are bouncing once. I don't know if it can be done on every mouseover.

Comment: if infinite is possible,if once is possible,than every mouseover animation should also be possible...i have been stuck at this for the past two hours but not able to figure out the solution!!!

Comment: @KeesSonnema:i tried it in fiddle but i dont know how to add images in that.not working in fiddle but working in my browser

Comment: Yes you can't have images in fiddle. only with a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" url. so you can just grap some images from google and put them in there.

Comment: you're only telling it to do it once, as you add the class once then leave it there, by the looks of it. Either remove the class on mouseout or better still, use the :hover pseudo class

Comment: @DavidStorey::considering your solution if i remove it on mouseout,would I need to add the class again on mouse over then???

Comment: Yes. You'd need to add it on mouseover and remove on mouseout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget the reset the classname,try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bounce(a) {
        document.getElementById(a).className = "animated bounce_css";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById(a).className = "hair_animate"; 
        },1000)
    }

</script>
```

Comment: what is that??hair_animate

Comment: @jayeshjain default class: <img src="images/single.png" id="hair1" class="**hair_animate**"  width="13" height="40" onmouseover="bounce(this.id);" >